# CalculateDefaultGridIndex

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3

Has anyone found that using CalculateDefaultGridIndex in arcGIS9.3 does not return the ';' delimited string suggested in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you use the 9.3 gp object there is an issue.

So I switched:

```
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
```

to:

```
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
```

Comment: Yes. In 9.3 it returns a result object, which you can call `str()` on to get the old string, or `result.getOutput(0)`